# Python: The code I typed isn't doing anything

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to do the bisection method using Python and when I try to run it, nothing happens.
Here's the code I used:

```
import math
a=0
b=1    
def f(x):    
    return math.sqrt(x)-math.cos(x)
while b-a>0.0001:    
    c=(a+b)/2
    if f(a)*f(c)>0:        
        a=c
else:
        b=c
print(c)
```

Comment: Please fix thy indentation. I have tried to rectify it. Rollback and edit it

Comment: It's doing something all right...forever. Use the debugger to find out what.

Comment: I would recommend adding print statements just after your `a=b` and `b=c` to troubleshoot *what* values are actually being seen.

Comment: Why did you take the answer you [already got](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630969/python-what-exactly-is-wrong-with-my-code-syntax-errors), break its indentation, and put it into another "why isn't my code working" question?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I figured starting over would have better chances of getting aid.

Comment: You already got help. So, again, why did you break the answer and put it into another "why doesn't it work" question? That kind of question will (as you saw in your previous question) get closed.

Comment: Actually Oscar, if you started over, as @TigerhawkT3 pointed out, the main issue is your `else` is not indented the same as the answer provided to you in that previous question.

Comment: @localhost Oh, I see. I appreciate you pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

1. the else belongs to the while.
2. c is defined inside the while
3. it seems like you push c value down?

Comment: I would add that `c` being defined in the while isn't an issue, actually as it is only `a` or `b` that should be modified at each iteration (at which point, `c` is "redefined"). In this context, `c` is defined in the place in the while loop before it is ever used (i.e. no `NameError`). However, #1 and #3 are **definitely** issues.

Comment: What do you mean by "push the c value down"?